# How to decompress files from an archive ignoring the file names?

Tags: filenames, archive

I have several ZIP and RAR archives where the filenames inside the archive are scrambled and they contain invalid filesystem characters like ?-s *-s or !-s or very long file and directory names that confuse the usual archiver tools or they simply fail to create the file. Since only the content matters I would just like to extract the files in these archives into a single directory in a flat structure with generic names like file0, file1, file2, etc... What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you can code a script in a language with a Zip library (such as Python) which will loop over the entries of the zipfile to extract them under a new name?

Comment: You're saying that the filenames inside the ZIP are corrupted? Or that the ZIP archive filename itself is corrupted?

Comment: @igeorget If that's the simlplest way. Though I have never programmed in Python yet.

Comment: @roaima The filenames inside the archive are corrupted.

Comment: Have you've tried `unzip -j broken.zip`

Comment: @roaima I tried it, but it still can't create the file, because it attempts to keep the original filename which is too long.

Comment: See also [rename files in a zip archive before extracting](http://superuser.com/q/491873) (there'a python solution there...)

Answer (score 3):

There is a Perl script written by Daniel S. Sterling available at https://gist.github.com/eqhmcow/5389877 (referenced from [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.html)) that looks like it could almost do what you need.

- Change line 46 to read `my $status, $filenumber = 0;`
- Comment lines 52-54 (put `#` at the beginning of each line)
- Change line 61 to read `my $destfile = "file" . $filenumber++;`

The entire script, with these modifications, is presented below for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# example perl code, this may not actually run without tweaking, especially on Windows

use strict;
use warnings;

=pod
IO::Uncompress::Unzip works great to process zip files; but, it doesn't include a routine to actually
extract an entire zip file.
Other modules like Archive::Zip include their own unzip routines, which aren't as robust as IO::Uncompress::Unzip;
eg. they don't work on zip64 archive files.
So, the following is code to actually use IO::Uncompress::Unzip to extract a zip file.
=cut

use File::Spec::Functions qw(splitpath);
use IO::File;
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw($UnzipError);
use File::Path qw(mkpath);

# example code to call unzip:
unzip(shift);

=head2 unzip
Extract a zip file, using IO::Uncompress::Unzip.
Arguments: file to extract, destination path
    unzip('stuff.zip', '/tmp/unzipped');
=cut

sub unzip {
    my ($file, $dest) = @_;

    die 'Need a file argument' unless defined $file;
    $dest = "." unless defined $dest;

    my $u = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new($file)
        or die "Cannot open $file: $UnzipError";

    my $status, $filenumber = 0;
    for ($status = 1; $status > 0; $status = $u->nextStream()) {
        my $header = $u->getHeaderInfo();
        my (undef, $path, $name) = splitpath($header->{Name});
        my $destdir = "$dest/$path";

        # unless (-d $destdir) {
        #     mkpath($destdir) or die "Couldn't mkdir $destdir: $!";
        # }

        if ($name =~ m!/$!) {
            last if $status < 0;
            next;
        }

        my $destfile = "file" . $filenumber++;
        my $buff;
        my $fh = IO::File->new($destfile, "w")
            or die "Couldn't write to $destfile: $!";
        while (($status = $u->read($buff)) > 0) {
            $fh->write($buff);
        }
        $fh->close();
        my $stored_time = $header->{'Time'};
        utime ($stored_time, $stored_time, $destfile)
            or die "Couldn't touch $destfile: $!";
    }

    die "Error processing $file: $!\n"
        if $status < 0 ;

    return;
}

1;
```